# Using JavaScript to set the value of a form element

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to learn JavaScript and in a particular excercise, I am trying to set the value of a button from a user input, but I keep getting an empty value. Where did I go wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Variables</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         FIRST_NAME = window.prompt("Enter your first name.");
         document.forms[0].username.value = FIRST_NAME;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <input type="button" value="Paul"
              onclick="alert('Paul');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="John"
              onclick="alert('John');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="George"
              onclick="alert('George');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Ringo"
              onclick="alert('Ringo');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" id="username" name="username" value=''
              onclick="alert(FIRST_NAME);"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: Its basically the timing of rendering script.Try to place script at the bottom of the body and try.It should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When shot the prompt, any elements is not loaded. You should do it after loaded.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Variables</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                FIRST_NAME = window.prompt("Enter your first name.");
                document.forms[0].username.value = FIRST_NAME;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <input type="button" value="Paul"
              onclick="alert('Paul');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="John"
              onclick="alert('John');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="George"
              onclick="alert('George');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Ringo"
              onclick="alert('Ringo');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" id="username" name="username" value=''
              onclick="alert(FIRST_NAME);"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onclick="alert(FIRST_NAME);"` is broken in this example.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when the contents of the `<script>` element are executed, the browser has not yet loaded/rendered the referenced form. Try moving the contents of the `<script>` element into a function and calling that function on the `onload` event.

```
<html>
    <head>
     <title>JavaScript Variables</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function init() {
          var FIRST_NAME = window.prompt("Enter your First Name.");
          document.forms[0].username.value = FIRST_NAME;
      }
     </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
    <form id="myForm">
     <input type="button" value="Paul"
       onclick="alert('Paul');"/>
     <br/><br/>
     <input type="button" value="John"
       onclick="alert('John');"/>
     <br/><br/>
     <input type="button" value="George"
       onclick="alert('George');"/>
     <br/><br/>
     <input type="button" value="Ringo"
       onclick="alert('Ringo');"/>
     <br/><br/>
     <input type="button" id="username" name="username" value=""
       onclick="alert(this.value);"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the script after the HTML element so that when the script is executed, it really has a DOM element to set value to. Try this code, it will tell you what `document.forms[0]` is when you are trying to access it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Variables</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           alert(typeof document.forms[0]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <input type="button" value="Paul"
                   onclick="alert('Paul');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="John"
                   onclick="alert('John');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="George"
                   onclick="alert('George');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Ringo"
                   onclick="alert('Ringo');"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" id="username" name="username" value=''
                   onclick="alert(FIRST_NAME);"/>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                FIRST_NAME = window.prompt("Enter your first name.");
                document.forms[0].username.value = FIRST_NAME;
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But a good way of doing it would be to create a function and call its BODY's onload method. Just replace you BODY tag with `<body onload="document.forms[0].username.value = window.prompt('Enter your first name.');">` and see what happens (of course, remove all other code that you put in to do the same).

Comment: if you were worried about FIRST_NAME, it is global.

Comment: If you don't like global variables, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435146/using-javascsript-to-set-value-of-a-form-element/6435166#6435166).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the form tag is not closed. So, maybe there is no valid form in the page and hence document.forms[0] is undefined.

**Before the close-body tag, add a close-form tag.**